# Steps to run applet on web browser (connect applet program to html) using Eclipse

Tags: java, applet

Hi friends I am new to Java. I am trying to display applet on web browser using Eclipse.

Code:

```
import java.applet.*;

import java.awt.*;

public class AppletDemo extends Applet{

    String msg="hello";

    public void init(){

        msg=getParameter("message");

    }

     public void paint(Graphics g){

        g.drawString(msg,80,80);

    }

}
```

Applet Tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>

<body>

<applet code="AppletDemo.class"width="350"height="350">

<param name="message"value="Welcome to the world of Applet">

</applet>

</body>

</html>
```

Output should be "Welcome to the world of Applet"
but when I run  it, no value is getting displayed.

i got output in console is:

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in

production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java

\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java

/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib

/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32

\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;.;C:\Users\RAJEEV4\Desktop

\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32(1)\eclipse;;.

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source'

to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demojsp' did not find a matching property.

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:40 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source'

to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Zdemoappletweb' did not find a matching property.

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 2323 ms

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Oct 20, 2014 12:43:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 1961 ms

What is the issue here?

Comment: even hello is not displaying?

Comment: my question is i can run this program from cmd but how to run same program by eclips("hello" is displaying when i run directly but how to display "Welcome to the world of Applet" in eclips ) please tell me steps.....

Comment: i am not getting any error..

Comment: i am getting title "Insert title here" then after a box with message "error: click here for detail" then there is a message "class not found exception". @SparkOn

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code ..


              import java.applet.Applet.*;
              import java.applet.*;
            import java.awt.*;
            public class Demo4 extends Applet
               {
                 public void paint(Graphics g)
              {
                  Font f=new Font("calibri",Font.BOLD,50);
                  g.setFont(f);
                 g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(0,0,1400,300);
               g.setColor(Color.yellow);
               g.fillRect(0,300,1400,600);
               g.setColor(Color.green);
               g.drawString("Welcome to the world of applet",100,200);  
               }
              }
                /*<applet code="Demo4.class" WIDTH=20 HEIGHT=20>
              </applet>*/
```

Here thre is no need to make applet tag direct run this code..u have to foloow these rule to run

for compile- javac Demo4.java
 for run- appletViewer Demo4.java

you get your ans easily..and don,t forget to include commen lines of applet these are the main lines

Comment: i know without applet tag it work.but i am trying to run my program with <applet>tag or<param>tag.so please tell me steps.......

Comment: here these last two comment line is used as applet tag so you have to run whole program including these comment tag lines..

Answer (score 0):

First compile the `AppletDemo` class then keep the `.class` and the `html` file in same location.
Then when you open the html file if you are getting error like

`Your security settings have blocked a local application from running`

Then just go to

*start - >control panel -> java(if unable to find type java in the search field of control panel) -> Then click on it a menu pops up go to security tab -> then make the security label to medium and ok.*

Then again open the html in browser it will ask to click on run this application thats it.